# How to connect AMLS to ADLS Gen 2?

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-data-lake-gen2

I would like to register a dataset from ADLS Gen2 in my Azure Machine Learning workspace (`azureml-core==1.12.0`). Given that service principal information is not required in the Python SDK [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.datastore.datastore?view=azure-ml-py#register-azure-data-lake-gen2-workspace--datastore-name--filesystem--account-name--tenant-id-none--client-id-none--client-secret-none--resource-url-none--authority-url-none--protocol-none--endpoint-none--overwrite-false-) for `.register_azure_data_lake_gen2()`, I successfully used the following code to register ADLS gen2 as a datastore:

```py
from azureml.core import Datastore

adlsgen2_datastore_name = os.environ['adlsgen2_datastore_name']
account_name=os.environ['account_name'] # ADLS Gen2 account name
file_system=os.environ['filesystem']

adlsgen2_datastore = Datastore.register_azure_data_lake_gen2(
    workspace=ws,
    datastore_name=adlsgen2_datastore_name,
    account_name=account_name, 
    filesystem=file_system
)
```

However, when I try to register a dataset, using

```py
from azureml.core import Dataset
adls_ds = Datastore.get(ws, datastore_name=adlsgen2_datastore_name)
data = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files((adls_ds, 'folder/data.csv'))
```

I get an error

> Cannot load any data from the specified path. Make sure the path is accessible and contains data.
> `ScriptExecutionException` was caused by `StreamAccessException`.
> StreamAccessException was caused by AuthenticationException.
> `'AdlsGen2-ReadHeaders'` for '[REDACTED]' on storage failed with status code 'Forbidden' (This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.), client request ID <CLIENT_REQUEST_ID>, request ID <REQUEST_ID>. Error message: [REDACTED]
> | session_id=<SESSION_ID>

Do I need the to enable the service principal to get this to work? Using the ML Studio UI, it appears that the service principal is required even to register the datastore.

Another issue I noticed is that AMLS is trying to access the dataset here:
`https://adls_gen2_account_name.**dfs**.core.windows.net/container/folder/data.csv` whereas the actual URI in ADLS Gen2 is: `https://adls_gen2_account_name.**blob**.core.windows.net/container/folder/data.csv`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-access-data#azure-data-lake-storage-generation-2),you need to enable the service principal.

1.you need to register your application and grant the service principal with **Storage Blob Data Reader access**.

[image]

2.try this code:

```
adlsgen2_datastore = Datastore.register_azure_data_lake_gen2(workspace=ws,
                                                             datastore_name=adlsgen2_datastore_name,
                                                             account_name=account_name,
                                                             filesystem=file_system,
                                                             tenant_id=tenant_id,
                                                             client_id=client_id,
                                                             client_secret=client_secret
                                                             )

adls_ds = Datastore.get(ws, datastore_name=adlsgen2_datastore_name)
dataset = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files((adls_ds,'sample.csv'))
print(dataset.to_pandas_dataframe())
```

**Result:**

[image]